# How can I read or download an image from a Google Sheet or google sheet cell using R?

Tags: r, image, google-sheets, download

This is what I tried:

```
library(googlesheets)
sheetPath = "urlToFile"
workSheetName = "sheetName"
gs_title("Gapminder") %>%
  gs_download(ws = "workSheetName ", to = "imageToSave.pdf")
```

I'm currently getting an authorization error.

Comment: You need first to authorize your account. Please follow this tutorial and highlight if any issues occurred. https://datascienceplus.com/how-to-use-googlesheets-to-connect-r-to-google-sheets/

Comment: thanks @NaremanDarwish. For some reason when I attempt to authorize and click on my account I keep getting this message: "Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app
This app has not been verified yet by Google in order to use Google Sign In."